# How does predicate logic handle contradictory statements about something that does not exist?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let

- **p** denote *ringing telephone*
- ***s*** denote *someone*
- **A** denote *answered*

  1. ¬∃x(Px)
  2. ∀x∃y((Px⋀Sy) →Ayx)
  3. ∀x¬∃y((Px⋀Sy) →Ayx)

So,

1. There are no ringing telephones.
2. Every ringing telephone was answered by someone.
3. Every ringing telephone was not answered by someone.

Those three statements could all be true. (I believe 'vacuously true' is the term.) How does propositional logic treat them? How would one prove they are not contradictory?

Comment: Are you asking what can be said about $1\land 2\land 3$?

Comment: "Propositional logic" does not have variables, predicates, or quantifiers at all.

Comment: And $\neg\exists p$ is not well-formed.

Comment: Also, 3 does not in any way contradict 2.

Comment: Revised the question

Comment: You cannot translate "someone" with a predicate $S$; "someone" will be expressed by the existential *quantifier*; see amWhy's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not "contradictory", or inconsistent.

Your translations are quite a bit off, which I think only adds to your confusion. (Taking the necessary time to create an appropriate key is essential.)

Key:

Let $Px $ denote "x is a phone".

Let $Sx$ denote "x is a person"

Let $Rx$ denote "x is ringing"

Let $Axy$ denote "x is answered by y".

Using the above key:

$(1)\quad \lnot \exists x(Px \land Rx)$.

$(2)\quad \forall x ((Px \land Rx) \implies \exists y(Sy \land Axy))$.

$(3)\quad \forall x ((Px \land Rx) \implies \lnot\exists y(Sy \land Axy))$.

The statements are **not** inconsistent, since each of $(2), (3)$ must be true because by $(1)$, the antecedent in each is false.

Comment: *(2),(3) must be true because by (1), the antecedent in each is false.* This suggests to me that ∀x→∃x? Is that always the case?

Comment: Anything at all follows from a false premise, and the implication still remains true. I don't understand what you mean by $\forall x \implies \exists x$?

Comment: For example: The antecedent in (2) is ∀x((Px∧Rx). You wrote that, '(2) must be true because by (1), the antecedent in is false.' I presume that the ¬∃x (which I translate as there does not exist an x) is responsible for the falsity of the antecedent in (2). If that's the case then it must be the case that ∀x implies that x exists (∀x→∃x): since ∃x is false in (1), then ∀x must also be false. I suspect I'm wrong, but that's my reasoning.

Comment: The antecedent I'm referring to is $(Px\land Rx)$. The sentence means "for all x (**If** (Px $\land$ Rx), **then** there exists a y(...)". Since there does not exist an x such that $Px \land Rx$, the implication is true (because it never happens that $Px \land Rx$.)

Comment: Right. I think we're saying the same thing. In order to say 'Any x, such that...' you have to also be able to say 'There is an x, such that...'. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hal - In order to understand : "(2),(3) must be true because by (1), the antecedent in each is false" you must remember that *(1)*, i.e.$\lnot \exists x(Px \land Rx)$, is equivalent to : $\forall x \lnot(Px \land Rx)$, and this is exactly the *negation* of the antecedent of *(2)* and *(3)*. Thus, if we assume *(1)* as *true* we cannot use it in *(2)* and *(3)* to conclude anything. This is why we have **no** contradiction.

Comment: @Hal - The two are **not** equivalent, because $P \land R$ is *true* only when **both** $P$ and $R$ are, while $P \rightarrow R$ may be *true* also when $P$ is *false*. If in the room there is a bell that is ringning, $\lnot \exists x (Px \land Rx)$ will still be false (there are no phones ringing) while $\lnot \exists x(Px \rightarrow Rx)$ becomes *true*.

Answer (score 1):

First, this if first-order logic and not propositional logic (as pointed out in the comments).

There is no contradiction in these three statements being true.

You seem to consider that 3 is the negation of 2, but actually the negation of 2 is

$ \exists p \forall s \neg(A~sp) $

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my question I noted that all three statements could be true.